# Disable multiline in FullCalendar 5.3.2

Tags: fullcalendar

I am having some troubles with FullCalendar and multiline, anyone knows how to disable the multine? I tried several things and search in documentation without success.

Thanks in advance.

[FullCalendar 5 multiline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hw7v.png)

Comment: It is a weekGrid. I would like to know how to disable the multiline in the Events.

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks - you can mess about with the HTML as much as you like